# Remove $obj from DOM without removing bound events listener from that object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have some jQuery objects with bound events that I am interchanging inside a container

```js
var $obj1 = $('<button type="button">Button 1</button>');
$obj1.click(function() { console.log("Button 1 clicked") });

var $obj2 = $('<button type="button">Button 2</button>');
$obj2.click(function() { console.log("Button 2 clicked") });

$("body").html($obj1);

//here the $obj1 click event listener is removed from $obj1
$("body").html($obj2);

//here nothing happen when I click on the Button 1
$("body").html($obj1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way I can add/remove jQuery object without having to bind the events listener every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove what you want from dom and listeners will still be available if you re-insert that object

```js
var $obj1 = $('<button type="button">Button 1</button>');
$obj1.click(function() { console.log("Button 1 clicked") });

var $obj2 = $('<button type="button">Button 2</button>');
$obj2.click(function() { console.log("Button 2 clicked") });

$("body").html($obj1);
$obj1.detach()

$("body").html($obj2);
$obj2.detach()
//click working now
$("body").html($obj1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the way you select/create your listener

```
$('body').on('click','button',function(){});
```

I would suggest adding a class or another way to identify which one you are looking for:

```
 $('body').on('click','button.first-button',function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of event delegation, using `on()`, an have a handler added to a parent of those buttons, which will catch their clicks.

With `event.target` you get the button clicked at.

*Also added `event.target.matches(selector)` to show how you can deal with other, existing, elements than the added buttons.*

Stack snippet

```js
$('.wrapper').on('click', function(event) {
  if( event.target.matches('button') ) {
    //do stuff for buttons
    console.log('button', event.target.textContent);
  }

  if( event.target.matches('a') ) {
    //do stuff for links
    console.log('link', event.target.textContent);
  }
});

var $obj1 = $('<button type="button">Button 1</button>');
var $obj2 = $('<button type="button">Button 2</button>');

$(".wrapper").append($obj1);
$(".wrapper").append($obj2);

$($obj1).remove();
$($obj2).remove();

$(".wrapper").append($obj1);
$(".wrapper").append($obj2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>
  <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your listeners using .on() as shown below. Then you can add some data attributes/classes to your buttons to be able to differentiate them in your click handler.

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    console.log('button clicked');
});
```

http://devdocs.io/jquery/on